# Why do fluids have pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, liquid-state

I am not able to understand that why fluids have pressure, in terms of newton's laws, and why do fluids have equal pressure in all directions at a point? However I know the story of weight of layer of liquid over the other which causes pressure difference but still it seems like this is not the whole story, I wanna know in terms of action reaction and forces.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: *"Due to the fundamental nature of fluids, a fluid cannot remain at rest under the presence of a shear stress. However, fluids can exert pressure normal to any contacting surface. If a point in the fluid is thought of as an infinitesimally small cube, then it follows from the principles of equilibrium that the pressure on every side of this unit of fluid must be equal. If this were not the case, the fluid would move in the direction of the resulting force."*

Comment: "*Thus, the pressure on a fluid at rest is isotropic; i.e., it acts with equal magnitude in all directions. This characteristic allows fluids to transmit force through the length of pipes or tubes; i.e., a force applied to a fluid in a pipe is transmitted, via the fluid, to the other end of the pipe. This principle was first formulated, in a slightly extended form, by Blaise Pascal, and is now called Pascal's law."* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatics#Pascal.27s_contribution_in_Hydrostatics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand when you say you know the cause of the pressure difference in a layer of liquid, but you do not understand why fluids have pressure. That is, the fluids have not pressure, they have **mass**, and they generate a pressure. In the same way that if you, who have a certain mass, you stand on a plate you will generate a force on the plate. This force is what we usually call weight, however, you might want to speak of the force that ejerces on the plate **per unit of surface**, this is, the **pressure**

```
In terms of Newton's laws?
```

Of course, if you want to obtain the *hydrostatic equation* you've to apply  the 2nd law

---

Briefly, considering the next test volume that is at rest.

[image]

The forces that keep in balance to the fluid portion are :

- The weight of the fluid layer  
   $\rho g Sdz$
- The force exerted by the fluid on its underside
   $pS$
- The force that exercises the fluid on its top face 
   $ (p+dp)S$

Balancing forces in the equilibrium

> $$pS - (p+dp)S - \rho g Sdz = 0 $$

Directly you get

$$ \frac {dp}{\rho} = -g.dz $$

Considering $\rho = constant$ you can integrate immediately between 1 and 2 so

> $$g(z_2 - z_1) = \frac {p_1-p_2}{\rho}$$

If we place point 2 on the surface, then $p_2 = $ atmospheric pressure $= p_0$

Of course, $z_2=0$ and the point A is at a depth $z_1=z$

So we get the pressure p to a specified depth z

> $$ p(z) = p_0 + \rho gz $$

---

```
why do fluids have equal pressure in all directions at a point?
```

Pascal's law

Please, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_law

Comment: Did you understand it? ? If so, you can thank the answer and the effort, no?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't pretend to be a formal answer, but if you filled a can with slippery spheres, can you see that they would push outwards on the walls of the can, and that the greater the height to which you filled the can, the greater the pressure they would exert, because the sideways pressure is ultimately due to the pull of gravity?